# HD 530 + GTX970 = blackscreen with nvidia optimus

Tags: xorg, nvidia, graphics, intel-graphics, graphic-card

I just bought [msi gs40 6qe](http://www.msi.com/product/notebook/GS40-6QE-Phantom.html#hero-overview). This laptop has skylake core i7 6700hq (which means integrated graphic HD 530) and discrete GTX 970. I'm struggling to start xorg on archlinux.

**I'm trying to run xorg withing `nvidia`** and `nvidia-libgl` packages as it described on [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA_Optimus) with modesetting. I added those ~/.xinitrc:

```
xrandr --setprovideroutputsource modesetting NVIDIA-0
xrandr --auto
```

I also have the same [xorg.conf](https://gist.github.com/Deathangel908/5e51a857eb600ce8bac8) as on wiki. But when I start xorg I get black screen.

```
[    9.205720] nvidia-modeset: Loading NVIDIA Kernel Mode Setting Driver for UNIX platforms  358.16
```

Here'are my, [xorg.log](https://gist.github.com/Deathangel908/a6683064b5c674fc3a16), and [dmesg](https://gist.github.com/Deathangel908/c000a303a02f16b1f25f) (those one with started sddm configured to plasma5 and `modesetting`). I'm installing up to date archlinux with 4.2.5-1 kernel  with [this](http://pastebin.com/wpmFi38k) patch. (Thus I got rid of `this pci device is not a vga device` message in kernel log.

Any kind of help is greatly appreciated. If you need any other configs or logs just tell me.

**EDIT:**

- Well, starting X first and then setting provider from another tty
  changed everything. Now Screen goes totally black(no backlight),
  until I set provider from tty2. Here's  [listproviders](https://gist.github.com/Deathangel908/e3837e2d3364979d914f), 
  [tty output](https://gist.github.com/Deathangel908/d3d11798d5b6f6654c82) and [xorg.log](https://gist.github.com/Deathangel908/7dc9d48a6f24dd950b98)  At least I got something....
- Here's [xorg.log](https://gist.github.com/Deathangel908/f0d86d3b32585165f8ca) if I set modprovider in ~/.xinitrc and startx. Xorgs terminates with 0 right after start.
- Here's [xorg.log](https://gist.github.com/Deathangel908/e0235b31e6c9a851cedf) with sddm and modeset in sddm/Xsetup - Screen goes black without backlight

Answer (score 0):

The black screen is x running properly. Without a .xinitrc file, when x starts nothing else is started to it is just a black screen. In order to start a window manager like twm and try it just
 pacman -S xorg-twm 
and then put
 exec xorg-twm in your ~/.xinitrc file and start x.

This can by any WM you want, my .xinitrc just has

```
exec awesome
```

so its likely a problem with the WM

Comment: X runs properly with blackscreen if backlight is on and there's black image. In my case backlight is off. I have installed xorg-twm and xclock should start since it drawing is set in /etc/X11/xinitrc by default. If I remove xclock I'll get no such programm error.